# Pandas groupby apply vs transform with specific functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I don't understand which functions are acceptable for `groupby` + `transform` operations. Often, I end up just guessing, testing, reverting until something works, but I feel there should be a systematic way of determining whether a solution will work.

Here's a minimal example. First let's use `groupby` + `apply` with `set`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,1,2,3,3], 'b':[1,2,3,1,2,3,3], 'type':[1,0,1,0,1,0,1]})

g = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['type'].apply(set)

print(g)

a  b
1  1    {0, 1}
2  2    {0, 1}
3  3    {0, 1}
```

This works fine, but I want the resulting `set` calculated groupwise in a new column of the original dataframe. So I try and use `transform`:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['type'].transform(set)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
---> 23 df['g'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['type'].transform(set)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'
```

This is the error I see in Pandas v0.19.0. In v0.23.0, I see `TypeError: 'set' type is unordered`. Of course, I can map a specifically defined index to achieve my result:

```
g = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['type'].apply(set)
df['g'] = df.set_index(['a', 'b']).index.map(g.get)

print(df)

   a  b  type       g
0  1  1     1  {0, 1}
1  2  2     0  {0, 1}
2  3  3     1  {0, 1}
3  1  1     0  {0, 1}
4  2  2     1  {0, 1}
5  3  3     0  {0, 1}
6  3  3     1  {0, 1}
```

But I thought the benefit of `transform` was to avoid such an explicit mapping. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe, in the first place, that there is some room for intuition in using these functions as they can be very meaningful.

In your first result, you are not actually trying to *transform* your values, but rather to *aggregate* them (which would work in the way you intended).

But getting into code, the `transform` docs are quite suggestive in saying that

> Return a result that is either the same size as the group chunk or broadcastable to the size of the group chunk.

When you do

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['type'].transform(some_func)
```

You are actually **transforming each `pd.Series` object from each group** into a new object using your `some_func` function. But the thing is, this new object should have the same size as the group **OR** be broadcastable to the size of the chunk.

Therefore, if you transform your series  using `tuple` or `list`, you will be basically transforming the object

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

into

```
[1,2,3]
```

But notice that these values are now *assigned back* to their respective indexes and that is why you see no difference in the `transform` operation. The row that had the `.iloc[0]` value from the `pd.Series` will now have the `[1,2,3][0]` value from the transform list (the same would apply to tuple) etc. Notice that *ordering* and *size* here matters, because otherwise you could mess up your groups and the transform wouldn't work (and this is exactly why `set` is not a proper function to be used is this case).

---

The second part of the quoted text says "broadcastable to the size of the group chunk".

This means that you can also transform your `pd.Series` to an object that can be used in all rows. For example

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['type'].transform(lambda k: 50)
```

would work. Why? even though `50` is not iterable, it is *broadcastable* by using this value repeatedly in all positions of your initial `pd.Series`.

---

Why can you `apply` using set?

Because the `apply` method doesn't have this constraint of *size* in the result. It actually has *three* different result types, and it infers whether you want to *expand*, *reduce* or *broadcast* your results. Notice that you can't *reduce* in transforming*

> By default (`result_type=None`), the final return type is inferred from the return type of the applied function.
>   result_type : {‘expand’, ‘reduce’, ‘broadcast’, None}, default None
>   These only act when `axis=1` (columns):
>
> 1. ‘expand’ : list-like results will be turned into columns.
> 2. ‘reduce’ : returns a Series if possible rather than expanding list-like
>      results. This is the opposite of ‘expand’.
> 3. ‘broadcast’ : results will be broadcast to the original shape of the DataFrame, the original index and columns will be retained.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that `transform` as a method can be used in its own right (without `groupby`) and has specific requirements. Having said this, in my experienced it's used *mostly* with groupby, which is why I was mistaken into believing anything that works with `groupby` + `apply` would work with `transform`.

Answer (score 3):

The result of the transformation is restricted to certain types. *[For example it can't be `list`, `set`, `Series` etc. -- **This is incorrect**, thank you @RafaelC for comment]* I don't think this is documented, but when examining the source code of `groupby.py` and `series.py` you can find those type restrictions.

From the `groupby` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

> The `transform` method returns an object that is indexed the same (same size) as the one being grouped. The transform function must:
>
> - Return a result that is either the **same size as the group chunk or broadcastable to the size of the group chunk** (e.g., a scalar, grouped.transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])).
> - Operate column-by-column on the group chunk. The transform is applied to the first group chunk using chunk.apply.
> - Not perform in-place operations on the group chunk. Group chunks should be treated as immutable, and changes to a group chunk may produce unexpected results. For example, when using fillna, inplace must be False (grouped.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(inplace=False))).
> - (Optionally) operates on the entire group chunk. If this is supported, a fast path is used starting from the second chunk.

Disclaimer: I got different error (`pandas` version 0.23.1):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['type'].transform(set)
File "***/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 3661, in transform
s = klass(res, indexer)        s = klass(res, indexer)
File "***/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 242, in __init__
"".format(data.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: 'set' type is unordered
```

---

#### Update

After transforming the group into a set, `pandas` can't broadcast it to the `Series`, because it is unordered (and have different dimensions than the group chunk) . If we force it into a list it will became same size as the group chunk, and we get only single value per row. The answer is to wrap it around in some container, so the resulting size of the object will become 1, and then `pandas` will be able to broadcast it:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['type'].transform(lambda x: np.array(set(x)))
print(df)

   a  b  type       g
0  1  1     1  {0, 1}
1  2  2     0  {0, 1}
2  3  3     1  {0, 1}
3  1  1     0  {0, 1}
4  2  2     1  {0, 1}
5  3  3     0  {0, 1}
6  3  3     1  {0, 1}
```

Why I chose `np.array` as a container? Because `series.py` (line 205:206) pass this type without further checks. So I believe this behavior will be preserved in future versions.

Comment: Strangely, `tuple` and `list` seem to work without error with v0.23, but not with the result I would expect. I guess the problem we're having is with the `broadcastable to the size of the group chunk` part. It seems Pandas can't "copy" a set / list, etc to all the members of a group.

Comment: I agree, that's why I emphasized that part. But since it is undocumented, and the code is being changed from version to version, I would not recommend to use anything in `transform` that return other than scalar, `numpy` vector or string.

Comment: @igrinis As a matter of fact, you *can* transform using `list` or `pd.Series`

Comment: @RafaelC You are right. Updating my answer and upvoting yours. Thank you and **jpp** for the interesting discussion.